Stripe React Native Custom Flow
I'm trying to use the paymentSheet with customFlow: true, however when I use the customFlow, it shows a different modal without the card and billing address showing by default, which is very confusing for the user.
Is there any way to keep the original paymentSheet and just switch the label on the button to "continue" as the documentation page shows?
customFlow: true

customFlow: false

The code I'm using is the following
await initPaymentSheet({
  merchantDisplayName: 'Cool brand',
  paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent,
  returnURL: '/checkout/success',
  defaultBillingDetails: {
    name: 'Jane Doe',
  },
  applePay: {
    merchantCountryCode: 'US',
  },
  googlePay: {
    merchantCountryCode: 'US',
    testEnv: true, // use test environment
  },
  customFlow: true,
})


No this isn't possible -- customFlow is meant to be used for a two-step process where the customer selects a PaymentMethod (or adds one) and you control the completion of the payment (see: docs), and thus the label for the button is "Continue". If you use the regular flow then the payment is completed upon the customer clicking the "Pay" button in the PaymentSheet hence why the label for the button in that case is "Pay".
In short, these button labels can't be customized.

It's not that I want to customize the label, but I would like to have the card element + billing open straightaway like the one without custom flow.
But I'm assuming is the same answer, right?

Ah then yes, that's correct.
